Producing A Chosen One Via Eugenics: Is It Possible?
Also Known As: The Ambrosius Problem
Lore if wanted: Long ago, the 12 most powerful mages in the world (the Founders), after gaining a pyrrhic victory against the Eldritch King, performed a ritual to make them and their followers immortal. Except, one of them opted out. Carmina Scarlotti, the world's most powerful Healer. And long story short, the ritual went wrong, and Carmina performed a "Blood Magic" ritual that should have killed her to save her fellow Founders, which caused the World's Largest Moonstone to react with her Blood Magic and turned her into an even more powerful being called an "Ambrosius". The first ever created.
TL;DR: There is a superhuman called the "First Ambrosius" who was created through a botched magic ritual.
The magic that made this human, Carmina, the First Ambrosius is tied specifically to two recessive genes she held, red hair and blue eyes. Specifically, one needs to inherit those two specific genes from Carmina, in their entirety, in order to be an Ambrosius. In case that isn't clear enough, if red hair is "rr" on the Punnet Square, and "bb" is blue eyes, you have to have your "rr" and "bb" inherited from Carmina herself.
And yet, as unlikely as this would be, there is a prophecy about a 2nd Ambrosius being born. Is this possible, without genetic engineering or inbreeding?
Clarification:

I'm not allowing inbreeding as a solution for reasons that should be obvious.
I understand eugenics ("selective breeding for humans") is a form of genetic engineering, but it isn't the kind of genetic engineering done in a lab, the kind that requires advanced technology, which for this specific case is unusable for Ambrosius production. (There are reasons, and they can be found at end of post if curious.)
Some sort of Punnett square or simple "descendance tree" diagram would be preferable. That said, I understand this may not be possible-I myself still lack the knowledge to put images into posts here-so it is not necessary. Punnet squares or descendence trees, as well as how many Ambrosius could be produced resulted over the course of a 1000 years of eugenics, would just be for bonus points.
How many generations before it's not considered inbreeding? I know 3rd cousins are pretty genetically distinct from each other, but I'd prefer a greater degree of separation. Lorewise, the program has a 1000 years to get results, so getting a pair of people with just the Blue-Eyed Ambrosius genes and the Red-Haired Ambrosius genes from their common descent maybe shouldn't be impossible? Could be wrong, I readily admit my lack of experience in this area!
There is a modern understanding of genetics in this setting. Which means genetic engineering to create an Ambrosius within a lab could be possible, if not for the plot reasons given at end of post.

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed!
Why They Can't Use Genetic Engineering?
It's because Carmina Scarlotti, much like Cynthia from Pokemon, had unsavory fans. One of which cloned her, which gave the others bad ideas. The clone's trauma, plus the depravity/idiocy of those interested in cloning Carmina, resulting in the Founders-friends of Carmina, mind you-laying down the strongest magic they could to forever bar any use of tech or magic to clone an Ambrosius or mess with her DNA at all.

This is tricky, since you do want to inbreed, but only one particular gene - the parents of the 2nd Ambrosius must have Identical-by-Descent gene copies that can directly be traced back to the 1st, since that DNA exists nowhere else in the population. This type of inheritance is much easier with fewer generations, but then you're also inbreeding all the other genes as well. Inbreeding isn't always bad, it can enrich beneficial traits (as done with livestock), but it can increase the odds of recessive disorders. If inbreeding can produce a demigod, I expect it might be more tolerated.

Both hair color and eye color in humans are polygenic traits. There is no "gene for blue eyes" and there is no "gene for red hair". Moreover, there are several strikingly different knids of blue eyes and of red hair. To get the exact shade of blue eyes and of red hair as the ancestress one must get the correct alleles for many different genes.

[tag:science-based] shall not be used alone

I apologize, Alendyias, I forgot to check your tags while your question was in the Sandbox. @L.Dutch is correct, per the tag's wiki, "This tag may not be used alone."

@L.Dutch: any suggestions on what tags I can use with it? Internal-consistency perhaps? I have it with genetics.

@Alendyias, please read the tag wiki. Internal consistency and science based are mutually exclusive

@Alendyias This is a question of genetics, so I've added that tag.

@MontyWild: thank you!

It's not a problem... as long as Carmina has had children, and the genes have continued to be passed down.
It appears that while Carmina had red hair and blue eyes, the two Ambrosius genes were linked to specific genes that influence these traits.  This means that as long as a descendant of Carmina has these genes homozygously (i.e. two identical copies of each of the two genes), they will be an Ambrosius.
So, as long as Carmina has descendants, it is possible for these genes to recombine into an Ambrosius at some point, without all the intermediate descendants having to be an Ambrosius.
We have the genes, "r" being Carmina's unique red-hair gene, and "R" being all other variants of that gene, and "b" being Carmina's unique blue-eyes gene, and "B" being all other variants of that gene
If we have Carmina and some unknown father, we have the following cross:
rrbb x RRBB -> 100% rRbB
All of Carmina's offspring will be heterozygous, having one copy of each of Carmina's two gene alleles.  Because they are heterozygous, none will be an Ambrosius.  Carmina's children may then mate with other people who are homozygous for non-Carmina alleles:
rRbB x RRBB -> ¼ rRbB, ¼ RRbB, ¼ rRBB, ¼ RRBB
At this point, in order for an Ambrosius to be possible in future generations, the "r" and "b" alleles must be passed on, though not necessarily to the same descendant.  This will probably require that Carmina's child or children have multiple children of their own... though only one child with the necessary alleles is strictly needed.
Now we get to the issue of Inbreeding.  Inbreeding is roughly defined as a relatedness of the parents of greater than 1/16, such as between first cousins.  However, inbreeding is not required to recreate an individual with the rrbb genotype, especially over a period of a thousand years with human generations of roughly 20 years, meaning that between Carmina and her prophesied Ambrosius descendant is a gap of around 50 generations.  With a 50 generation gap, relatedness would be as little as 1 in 2^51, or 1 in 2.25E15.
So, as long as the Carmina alleles "r" and "b" remain in the population and don't become extinct, over the generations, we can expect that they may become present in many of Carmina's descendants.  After a sufficient number of generations (4 or more), we wouldn't really consider a cross between those descendants to be inbreeding, and if Carmina's immediate descendants became geographically separated, this could mean that it would be many generations between the alleles "r" and "b" could recombine.
There are several ways that an Ambrosius could occur with non-Ambrosius parents, for example:
RrBb x RrBb -> 1/16 rrbb...
RrBb x Rrbb or RrBb x rrBb -> ⅛rrbb...
rrBb x Rrbb -> ¼rrbb...
As can be seen from the above, a cross between to parents heterozygous for each Carmina allele will produce an Ambrosius with a probability of 1/16.  A cross between a Carmina-blue-eyed individual or a Carmina Red-Haired individual who is heterozygous for the other gene allele with a heterozygous individual will produce an Ambrosius with a probability of 1/8.  A cross between a Carmina-blue-eyed individual and a Carmina Red-Haired individual, who are both heterozygous for the other Carmina gene will produce an Ambrosius with a probability of 1/4.
So, TL:DR, as long as the Carmina Red Hair and Carmina Blue Eyes genes are both passed down through the generations, it is possible for another Ambrosius to be born.  While these crosses do involve a cross between two of Carmina's descendants, it wouldn't be considered inbreeding after 4 generations or so.  Over the span of 1000 years or 50 generations, a union between Carmina's descendants wouldn't be considered to be inbreeding.

Thank you! This pretty well explains that time is the most important factor, as long as the genes are passed on. And that inbreeding isn't an issue!

This is fine for Mendelian traits that are defined by a single genetic locus. The problem is that the OP states that the genes in question must be inherited "in their entirety" (although they do also describe it as a simple recessive trait). It's simple to get certain alleles, but recombination will make the inheritance of an entire gene much less likely over generations.

Was Carmina a mutant?
You describe her as carrying two distinct recessives. Either she got them from both of her parents, or Carmina is a mutant in the technical sense.
Assume that her parents both carried a copy of each recessive, with or without a dominant to suppress it. Any sibling of Carmina might carry the same genes. Same for cousins. So the schemers would encourage Carminas cousins on different sides -- who are not biologically related -- to marry.

Ooooh, this is cool! Yes, the magic infusion into the recessives she  might count as a mutation and make Carmina a technical mutant. However, it appears I did not make something clear in my post. Carmina is the only person with the altered recessive genes. Sorry.

@Alendyias, even then someone with the same pre-magical recessives might be a candidate for the same magical transformation. Have conspiracies try to trace Carmina's family tree, make matches between likely relatives, etc.

that's a great idea, thank you! That'd be a great subplot!

Pedigree collapse
It is not humanly possibly to have all distinct ancestors.  Every human being alive today would need to have had about a billion ancestors in the time of the High Middle Ages, when there were not that many people alive.
And the total human population is the ceiling, not the floor.  It is very likely that the breeding population is smaller than that.  Even if they disallow first cousin marriages, second cousin or third cousin ones will occur, and if they disallow second or third, they will have fourth cousin marriages -- and probably second or third as well because people don't know their family trees back that far.
If you wish to increase the odds, the traits can be regarded as attractive or lucky so they are more likely to marry up and so be able to support many children, and keep them alive, thus increasing the frequency.  Or there may be a superstitious belief that those with one of those traits are better off marrying another, or even that it's impious not to because of the prophecy.

The Wikipedia page for pedigree collapse has a diagram of Cleopatra VII's (speculative) ancestry that goes a long way toward showing that OP's worldbuilding goal is well within the realm of possibility. And wow.


I'm not allowing inbreeding as a solution for reasons that should be obvious.

Perhaps those reasons are not as obvious in real life as in the popular imagination.
It is a fact that a recessive gene will not be expressed unless the person inherits two copies of it, one from the father and one copy from the mother.
So a person or other organism will not suffer from the negative effects of two copies of a undesireable recessive gene like Carmina's unless they inherit two copies of it, one from the father and one copy from the mother.
I also note that there is little way to tell whether a person has one copy of a recessive gene, since that gene will not be expressed in a person who has only one copy of it.
I also note that your question gives no indication that the society has a modern scientific understanding of genetics.
According to modern understanding of genetics a person who inherits two copies of a "bad" gene will have that bad gene expressed and it will be bad for their health.  Everyone has some "bad" recessive genes, so any random pair of persons will have a chance of their offspring inherited two copies of a "bad" gene and thus suffering from it.
And if a couple are more closely related than a limit, and thus share more genes than a randomly selected couple, their offspring will have a higher probability than  average of having two copies of "bad" recessive genes.  The more closely related they are, the higher the probability of their offspring inheriting two copies of "bad" recessive genes will be, and thus the higher the probability that the offspring will have bad health or other undesirable traits with genetic causes.
Mating between two second cousins has a probability of genetic problems for the offspring whichis no higher than average. Mating between two first cousins has a higher probability of the offspring inheriting genetic problems that average.
Mating between siblings or between parent and child has an even higher probability of genetic problems in the offspring.
It is a matter of probability, not of certainty.
Many royal families have practiced greater or lesser degrees of inbreeding, and varying degrees of genetic problems have resulted.

While this is, interesting, the inbreeding avoidance is for moral reasons not just logistical ones. I also fail to see how the specific recessive genes mentioned are "undesireable". That said, I do appreciate your point that a modern genetic understanding may be useful, and the setting would indeed have that. I'll edit the OP.
